# HTML/Rails: Button Next To Form_Tag automatically Submit?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to put a favorite button next to an add to cart button. The add to cart button happens to be implemented as a form-submit button, while the favorite button calls a remote ajax call, completley unrelated from the back end. The favorite button works beautifully on other pages, yet when I put it next to the add to cart button it suddenly turns into a submit form button!

```
<%=submit_tag "Add to Cart"%> | <%=get_fav_store_item_button(@store_item,@current_user)%>
```

It was suggested that I was still in the form block, but when I add an end after the submit I get and error "unexpected keyword ensure". Here is the whole form with the offending <%end%>:

```
<%=form_tag add_to_cart_path%>
<% if !store_option_types.empty? %>
    <h1>Add Options!</h1>
    <%store_option_types.each do |key,value|%>
        <%= render :partial=> 'option_selection', :locals => {:store_option_type => StoreOptionType.find(key), :options => value}%>
    <%end%>
<%else%>
    No options available for this order
<%end%>
<%hidden_field_tag "store_id", @store_item.store_id%>
<%hidden_field_tag "store_item_id", @store_item.id%>
<%=submit_tag "Add to Cart"%>
<%end%> | <%=get_fav_store_item_button(@store_item,@current_user)%>
```

As requested, the fav button script:

```
  def get_fav_store_button(item, user)
   existing_record = UserFavStore.where(:store_id=>item.id, :user_id=>user.id)
    if !existing_record.empty?
      return button_to("♥",add_fav_item_from_search_path(:user_id=>user.id, :store_id =>item.id),
    :id=>"S"+item.id.to_s,:class=>"fav_button fav_yes btn", :remote=>true)
  else
    return button_to("♥",add_fav_store_from_search_path(:user_id=>user.id, :store_id =>item.id),
    :id=>"S"+item.id.to_s,:class=>"fav_button btn", :remote=>true) #No fav_yes class!
  end
```

What is the cause of this, and how can I fix it? Perhaps it is a general html-form phenomena?

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow. Can you please edit your question and add the relevant section of html that this turns into (right click and view source on the page and copy it out). It's very hard to debug a verbal description of the problem. what do you mean when you say "it turns into a submit button"? Can you explain what you expect and what you got instead? is it just visual or something else? can you include images?

Comment: Can you please add all of your code including the ajax request? I'm guessing it is because the favourite button is in your `form_for` block.

Comment: Check out the updated question

Comment: The get_fav_store_button method is missing an end at the bottom unless it was pasted incorrectly. What's the error when you move the method call to the method `<%=get_fav_store_item_button(@store_item,@current_user)%>` outside of the block? I could be completely wrong here but you are using button_to in the get_fav_store_button method which is wrapped in the form_tag block. Might be causing the incorrect submit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were intending this line:

```
<%=form_tag add_to_cart_path%>
```

To begin a block that extends to the `submit_tag "Add to Cart"`

```
<%=form_tag add_to_cart_path do -%>
  <% if !store_option_types.empty? %>
    <h1>Add Options!</h1>
    <%store_option_types.each do |key,value|%>
      <%= render :partial=> 'option_selection', :locals => {:store_option_type => StoreOptionType.find(key), :options => value}%>
    <%end%>
  <%else%>
    No options available for this order
  <%end%>
  <%hidden_field_tag "store_id", @store_item.store_id%>
  <%hidden_field_tag "store_item_id", @store_item.id%>
  <%=submit_tag "Add to Cart"%>
<%end -%>
```

That is Form#1.  Form#2 should begin with the AJAX method.  Because there isn't an error being thrown right now, there's likely a misaligned block somewhere else in the code also.